# Xcode: Getting warning "implicit conversion from enumeration type UIDeviceOrientation"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

Full warning:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation'
```

Getting it on the line:

```
[self orientationChanged:interfaceOrientation];
```

This is the method:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

I can't really understand where this warning is coming from.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`UIDeviceOrientation` refers to the physical orientation of the device whereas `UIInterfaceOrientation` refers to the orientation of the user interface. When you call your method

```
[self orientationChanged:interfaceOrientation];
```

you are most likely passing it a `UIDeviceOrientation` when you should, according to the method, be using a `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

Just to expand on this point a bit, `UIDeviceOrientation` is a property of the `UIDevice` class, and there are these possible values:

> `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` - Can't be determined
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` - Home button facing down
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` - Home button facing up
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` - Home button facing right
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` - Home button facing left
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` - Device is flat, with screen facing up
>
> `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown` - Device is flat, with screen facing down

As for `UIInterfaceOrientation`, it is a property of `UIApplication` and only contains 4 possibilities which correspond to the orientation of the status bar:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,

UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

To get `UIDeviceOrientation`, you use

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

and to get `UIInterfaceOrientation`, you use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

Comment: Just ran into this problem again and you saved me again. I wish I could upvote you twice.