# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, uideviceorientation

I am getting the above compiler warning for the code below. I understand the difference between Interface and Device orientation, but am unsure how to amend to remove the warning. Can anyone help ?

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (ViewController != NULL) {
    [ViewController configureForDeviceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
if (Controller != NULL) {
    [Controller configureForDeviceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
currentOrientation = toInterfaceOrientation;
}
```

Comment: can you put method signature for **configureForDeviceOrientation** method

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015709/xcode-getting-warning-implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-uideviceorient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just cast it `[Controller configureForDeviceOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation];`

Comment: Thanks - good idea and works well here as the same method is being used correctly elsewhere.

Comment: actually it considered "bad practice" :)

Comment: I tried the same as: `UIDeviceOrientation orientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];` but a new warning: `Enumeration values 'UIDeviceOrientationUnknown', 'UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp', and 'UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown' not handled in switch`  any escape?

Comment: I think there is no escape just one solution (work around) to have switch case to handle these 3 interfaceOrientations. Anyhow I don't need these three to be handled at all in this scenario. @Ohnomycoco it is indeed a bad practice. its a cul-de-sac but.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `configureForDeviceOrientation:` is expecting to be passed a `UIDeviceOrientation` enum and not a `UIInterfaceOrientation` which you are passing in.

If you correct your method to accept a `UIInterfaceOrientation` from the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method, then you'll resolve the issue.