# Knowing the interface orientation of an iPad at application start

Tags: ipad, orientation

I am trying to figure out my iPad's orientation at start up on a flat table.

I always says it's starting in portrait mode, which it isn't true.

I have used the code sampled [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2011/09/22/how-to-determine-ios-device-orientation-when-your-app-starts-up/) to detect the orientation at start up.

It so happens that when my device is face up on a flat surface it claims it is in portrait mode. However the status bar is visually in landscape mode.

Is there a way around this?

I am using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.3.

**EDIT: More details**

Here is my update orientation method:

```
- (void)updateOrientation {

    UIInterfaceOrientation iOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    UIDeviceOrientation dOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    bool landscape;

    if (dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {
        // If the device is laying down, use the UIInterfaceOrientation based on the status bar.
        landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(iOrientation);
    } else {
        // If the device is not laying down, use UIDeviceOrientation.
        landscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(dOrientation);

        // There's a bug in iOS!!!! http://openradar.appspot.com/7216046
        // So values needs to be reversed for landscape!
        if (dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) iOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        else if (dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) iOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

        else if (dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) iOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        else if (dOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) iOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }

    whiteView.hidden = NO;
    splashScreen.hidden = NO;
    if (landscape) {
        splashScreen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape~ipad"];
    } else {
        splashScreen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad"];
    }

    splashScreen.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:whiteView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:splashScreen];

    // Set the status bar to the right spot just in case
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:iOrientation];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (splashScreen){
        [self updateOrientation];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                         animations:^{
                             splashScreen.alpha = 0;
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL success){
                             [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                             splashScreen = nil;
                         }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                         animations:^{
                             whiteView.alpha = 0;
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL success){
                             [whiteView removeFromSuperview];
                             whiteView = nil;
                         }];
}
```

The problem is noticeable when I start my app in a flat surface in landscape mode I see the wrong image being loaded up for the spashscreen.

Answer (score 5):

Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` instead of `[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`.

There's a difference between device orientation and user interface orientation (and [some elaboration can be found on this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015709/xcode-getting-warning-implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-uideviceorient)).  Many apps might have a user interface designed to only work certain ways even though the device is pointed another way.

Comment: I am using both of them. And when `UIDeviceOrientation` is faceup or face down I use `UIIinterfaceOrientation`from the status bar. But it would seem that at launch it doesn't know it is in landscape.

Comment: I have added more info to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same problem, and I have not found any good solution.

It seems that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` always return 1 before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has finish, and only if your device is face up (maybe face down too, i have not tried)

I finally done this :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // For the cases where device is not face up.
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        [self doTheJobInPortrait];
    else
        [self doTheJobInLandscape];

    // For the cases where device is face up
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(hackForFaceUpLandscapeDevices) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)hackForFaceUpLandscapeDevices {
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        [self doTheJobInPortrait];
    else
        [self doTheJobInLandscape];
}
```

Of course, the job will be done two times, and in face up lanscape mode there will be a short moment where your interface will be in portrait...

If someone find a better solution, I would be glad to know it.

Answer (score 0):

That's why there is often used a 'blank view' at startup, that just initializes your app. When the first view is laoded, you can easily check for the correct device-orientation.

After this you load your device-orientation-specific View. So you have:

One ViewController
One Blank View
Two Views with content (one landscape, one portrait)

I think, e. g. Safari Mobile does it that way.