# iPad doesnt recognize correct interface orientation on start?

Tags: ipad, startup, device-orientation

I have app that can start in portrait or landscape mode. Controls on main screen look differently depending in which mode application is.

Here is the problem - if i start application in landscape mode, controls arent where they should be, they retain their positions like app is portrait mode. I tried to test this a little bit, and here is what I found -

in viewDidLoad and ViewWillappear i get info that app is in portrait mode, although app is landscape mode. In view did appear it is set to correct value - landscape mode. Problem is i want these components to be set on their proper positions, before view appears (if don't i can clearly see them reposition on screen).

What is proper way to handle this?

EDIT:
in viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear, i call this:

```
orientation = [self getOrientation];
if (orientation == OrientationsLandscape) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Portrait");
}
```

here is implementation of [getOrientation]

```
 - (int) getOrientation {
    int currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(currentOrientation)) return OrientationsPortrait;
    else return OrientationsLandscape;
}
```

and enumeration def:

```
typedef enum {
     OrientationsLandscape = 0,
     OrientationsPortrait
} Orientations;
```

Now if device is landscape mode and i try to install my app, i will get 2 times printed "Portrait", instead "Landscape"

Comment: I have the same problem, but only when the device is face up. If I keep it in hands, inclined, the orientation is recognised. If I call a timer that make the test after initialisation, it works. But between applicationDidFinishLaunching and my timer call, i have a short white screen... Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I posted the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763842/127493

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

Comment: i am already using that to find out correct interface orientation, but as i sad its returning wrong orientation.

Comment: So try this [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation. One of them always shows correct orientation.

Comment: [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation is not correct for this use, you must use [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation

Comment: I know, but MegaManX says [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation doesn't work. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

As importantly, make sure you have correctly set the `autoresizingMask` property of all your UI elements.
Secondly, when I have this problem I fixed it in the init method. In the init you should control the iPad orientation like SVGreg suggest and than set the correct frame to your UI elements.

Comment: In the init method there is no way to know what your user interface orientation is. You can guess orientation based on device orientation, but problem is what if user locks orientation - thats why interface orientation should be used.

Comment: The default orientation is considered Portrait. If the orientation is Portrait nothing happens, instead if the orientation in Landscape the rotation method are called.