# Face Up orientation iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

Can i somehow disable the Face Up orientation in my iPhone app? OR can i handle it somehow?

It distorts the app's view when kept on flat table.

Comment: this might help u understand the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015709/xcode-getting-warning-implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-uideviceorient

Answer (score 1):

Go to project settings in XCode , click on your target and choose "summary".
Then you'll be able to see under "iPhone/iPod deployment" the following section.
Just remove portrait/upside down and you're set.

[image: interface orientations]

Comment: Do you even know what is the difference between Face Up and Upside Down orientations?

Comment: oh snap… 
sorry mate, i misread the question. In that case should use the proximity sensor, combined with accelerometer.. 
you should edit your question tough, as its tags are suggestion interface orientation, not detecting a flat surface