# Phonegap 2.4.0 Value Conversion Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm getting an error when I create a new project skeleton using phonegap 2.4 in my CDVLocation.m file. The error I'm getting is 
`if ([cdvViewController supportsOrientation:currentOrientation])` 
*Implicit conversion from enumeration type "UIDeviceOrientation"(aka "enum UIDeviceOrientation") to different enumeration type "UIInterfaceOrientation" (aka "enum UIInterfaceOrientation")*


Im not 100% sure whats going on here since I dont know OBJ-C, any idea?

Comment: can you see the implementation of `supportsOrientation:` i think its a custom method

Comment: I think, like I said I dont know OBJ-C so I'm guess this is it.<br>
`- (BOOL)supportsOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return [self.supportedOrientations containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation]];
}`

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015709/xcode-getting-warning-implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-uideviceorient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentOrientation` is of type `UIDeviceOrientation` which has more values than`UIInterfaceOrientation`

Since the method expects a `UIInterfaceOrientation` instead of a `UIDeviceOrientation`

**Replace:**

- <strike>`supportsOrientation:currentOrientation`</strike>
  with
- `supportsOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]]`

Try changing the method in CDVLocation.m:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(headingOrientation)]) {
    UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (currentOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) {
        CDVViewController* cdvViewController = (CDVViewController*)self.viewController;

        //change this line
        if ([cdvViewController supportsOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]]) {
            self.locationManager.headingOrientation = (CLDeviceOrientation)currentOrientation;
            // FYI UIDeviceOrientation and CLDeviceOrientation enums are currently the same
        }
    }
}
```